# CreateInput javascript dont allows space

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below script

```
// Add new record
$(document).on("click","."+editbutton,function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id && editing == 0 && tdediting == 0){
        // hide editing row, for the time being
        $("."+table+" tr:nth-child(2)").fadeOut("fast");

        var html;
        html += "<td>"+$("."+table+" tr[id="+id+"] td:first-child").html()+"</td>";
        for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
            // fetch value inside the TD and place as VALUE in input field
            var val = 'landi doda';
            input = createInput(i,val);
            html +='<td>'+input+'</td>';
        }
        html += '<td><a href="javascript:;" id="'+id+'" class="'+updatebutton+'"><img src=""><img src="" class="eimage"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></a> <a href="javascript:;" id="'+id+'" class="'+cancelbutton+'"><img src="" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>';

        // Before replacing the TR contents, make a copy so when user clicks on 
        trcopy = $("."+table+" tr[id="+id+"]").html();
        $("."+table+" tr[id="+id+"]").html(html);   

        // set editing flag
        editing = 1;
    }
});
```

If the val is just one word with no space then my table row for editing fill with inputs and it works perfectly.

But my problem is when i have on the val one word that contains space then my table row for editing fill only the first word of whole word,it does not take the spaces

Create input function

```
createInput = function(i,str){
    str = typeof str !== 'undefined' ? str : null;
    //alert(str);
    if(inputType[i] == "text"){
        input = '<input type='+inputType[i]+' name='+columns[i]+' placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'" value='+str+' >';
    }else if(inputType[i] == "textarea"){
        input = '<textarea name='+columns[i]+' placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'">'+str+'</textarea>';
    }
    else if(inputType[i] == "select"){
        input = '<select name='+columns[i]+'>';
        for(i=0;i<selectOpt.length;i++){
            //console.log(selectOpt[i]);
            selected = "";
            if(str == selectOpt[i])
                selected = "selected";
            input += '<option value="'+selectOpt[i]+'" '+selected+'>'+selectOpt[i]+'</option>';
        }
        input += '</select>';
        //console.log(str);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Where is this `createInput` function? post it! Its probably split the value and take the first token.

Comment: i have edited look above

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. A demo would be very helpful

Comment: @charlietfl i cant post whole my code cuz is very big app...the problem is on the above code i have posted.But i dont know how to fix it for the moment.Something on the function createInput split the text and take the first token

Comment: You don't need whole code...just enough to reproduce the problem. Doesn't need to be pretty either

Comment: My problem is on function createInput...nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to quote `str` like you did for placeholder.

```
... placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'" value='+str+' >';
```

should be:

```
... placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'" value="'+str+'" >';
```

Comment: @RolandDova quote the name attribute too! so you won't get problem there as well.

Comment: @RolandDoda in matter of fact. They all should be quoted.

Comment: Well it does not work yet..but i think i have to do some changes and then i ansered to you cuz i hurried